# Devexpress MultiSelect Row Field Name .?

Tags: devexpress, xtragrid

How can I determine whether Xtragrid in multiselect=True mode check button is selected during the GridviewButton event? See the grid image below:

[image]

Comment: it would help if you post the grid definition and GridviewButton event code.

Comment: Which "GridViewButton" event? You can always use the GridView's [IsRowSelected method](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnView_IsRowSelectedtopic) to determine if a particular row is selected (in which case the checkbox would also be checked)

Comment: Selected check box true I want to calculate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved   --

gridView1_SelectionChanged

```
var view = sender as GridView;
            if (view == null) return;
            view.BeginSelection();
              int[] selectedRows = view.GetSelectedRows();
                int[] RowHandle = view.GetSelectedRows();

            try
            {

                for (int i = -1; i < selectedRows.Length; i++)
                {
                    if (selectedRows.Length == 0)
                    {
                       clear();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //Clear all value zero 
                foreach (int value in RowHandle)
                  {    deger += Convert.ToDouble(gridView1.GetRowCellValue(value, "FieldName"));    } 

                   }
                }
```